# Javascript Object Weight/Size affect performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, object

In My project I usually I prefix all my JS object with my project name like if my project is `XXX`  I will have all my lib as `XXX.search`, `XXX.popup`, `XXX.login` , `XXX.login.sso` etc.. so that all my object comes under `XXX`.  Basically I am loading my `XXX` object with lot of modules.  So the `xxx` object become huge.

Will it affect JS performance in any case.

What is good practice, having every module separate or having all the modules under my object.

Or it doesn't matter both gives same performance effect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919677/is-it-better-to-have-one-large-object-in-javascript-or-many-smaller-ones

Answer (score 1):

Implementing namespacing with `Object`s is a pretty common JavaScript pattern. Nearly everything is an object in JavaScript, so I don't see how using Object literals to namespace things would exact any significant extra costs. Even if there is a significant cost to using objects as namespacing, I think that the benefit of working with clean code would outweigh it.

Addy Osmani writes a lot about these topics. I suggest you start [his article on the subject](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) if you're having trouble. Also keep in mind that there are many alternatives to objects as name spaces, like [immediately invoked function expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (though these incur a cost as well).

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer, I agree keeping code clean is more important.  So you are saying there wont be any performance impact on either way.?  Even the object is huge right?

Comment: I'm saying that if you want to implement name spacing at all, there is a cost. The tradeoff is that you get a more robust application in exchange for performance. Realistically, you have to do some kind of namespacing to build production-quality apps. Think about the jQuery object and how big that is. Do you find the performance of jQuery to be a hindrance in your projects?